# How can I get 'pk' or 'id' in `get_context_data` from CBV?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

How can I get 'pk' or 'id' in `get_context_data` from CBV DetailView?

```
class MyDetail(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(MyDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['something'] = Book.objects.filter(pk=pk)
            return context
```

url:

```
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', MyDetail.as_view(), name='book'),
```

Comment: In template use like `something.0.pk`

Comment: I confused due to CVB do you means Class Based Views (CBV)?..

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can get it from `self.kwargs['pk']`.

I'm not sure why you want to, though, since the superclass already gets the Book corresponding to that pk - that's the whole point of a DetailView.

Comment: My queryset looks different (is more complex). Book.objects.filter(pk=pk) is just example. Thanks.

Comment: This is such a common mistake, this answer should be pinned to the top!

Answer (score 8):

```
class MyDetail(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(MyDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['something'] =Book.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            return context
```

Answer (score 7):

`self.kwargs['pk']` it doesn't work in Django 2.2

> in DetailView
>
> self.object is the object that this view is displaying.
>
> So, to access the object's fields like `id` or `pk` just `self.object.id` or `self.object.pk`

**So, The answer in Django 2.2 can be like:**

```py
class MyDetail(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['something'] = Book.objects.filter(pk=self.object.pk)    # <<<---
            return context
```

[Django 2.2 Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)

Answer (score 5):

In get_context_data you already have the object in self.object (and you can do self.object.pk). Here's what happens upstream in the class hierarchy (DetailView inherits from BaseDetailView):

```
class BaseDetailView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
"""
A base view for displaying a single object
"""
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Reading Django source code to understand stuff is incredibly easy.

And by the way, I am not sure you can always rely on the fact that kwargs has a 'pk' key.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to getting it from `self.kwargs` as Daniel Roseman suggested, you can use `self.get_object().pk`, for example if you change your URL identifier from `pk` to, say, `slug` or something.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply get it in the 'get' method, like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['something'] =Book.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    return context
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_context_data(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['something'] =Book.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    return context
```

Filter returns a query set that matches the lookup parameter (pk). Since 'pk' is unique, it would return the same results as get but for performance issues, ideally you'd want to use the get method to return one single object:

```
def get_context_data(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['something'] =Book.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    return context
```